Historical data about military deaths
Where can I download the data behind this graph, or similar?
https://www3.nd.edu/~dhoward1/Rates%20of%20Death%20in%20War.pdf

The note at the bottom of the plot references the Battle Deaths Dataset. So, I think this it: loc.gov link. Note you can download the ZIP file, which includes an Excel.
